# Inherit parent privately while inheriting its grandparent publicly in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

The title says it. `Parent` exposes `Grandparent` publicly, and I want to keep it public in `Child`, but I want to hide the `Parent` itself. I don't see why this shouldn't be possible, but I can't find a way to use a `using` directive to achieve that. If I can use `using` to publicly expose privately inherited member variables, I expect to be able to do the same for privately inherited bases, but I can't seem to be able to find a syntax for that. An explicit conversion operator in `Child` might work, but is there a cleaner way?

```
class Grandparent {};

class Parent: public Grandparent {};

class Child: Parent
{
  // How can I expose Grandparent here publicly?
};

void takeGrandparent( Grandparent const & );

int main()
{
  takeGrandparent( Child() ); // error: cannot cast 'Child' to its private base class 'Grandparent'
}
```

UPD: since people have asked why I needed this, here's my use case. `Grandparent` is an interface which `Parent` implements. I want `Child` to use `Parent` to implement and provide this interface, but otherwise keep `Parent` private.

Comment: Perhaps you could use an implicit conversion operator to `Grandparent&`. Edit : It seems like private inheritance hides an implicit conversion operator to `Grandparent&`...

Comment: Please explain why you need such strange behavior. There might be a better design that will work for your needs without pulling crazy stunts like that.

Comment: If I can use `using` to publicly expose privately inherited member variables, why can't I do the same for privately inherited bases? I don't see any fundamental differences here, so I don't think what I'm asking for is unreasonable

Comment: Please read [What is the X Y problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)  The comment from R Sahu is very on point.  It's likely that the answer to your problem is that you don't need to do this.

Comment: Child is a Grandparent, but not a Parent. Parent is a Grandparent too. I see exactly no problem here.

Comment: I've updated the question with the description of my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit `Grandparent` also directly. This requires `virtual` inheritance, as is usually the case with multiple inheritance.

```
class Grandparent {};

class Parent: virtual public Grandparent {};

class Child: Parent, virtual public Grandparent
{
  // No special treatment needed, interface is inherited automatically
};
```

This actually makes sense in the context of the idea of private inheritance. You may think of private inheritance as "I am too lazy to add a `Parent` member to `Child`, so I'll implement it with inheritance instead". If you do it "properly" with composition, it becomes more like regular code with delegation:

```
class Grandparent
{
public:
    virtual int GrandparentMethod() {return 8;}
};

class Parent: public Grandparent {};

class Child: public Grandparent
{
public:
    virtual int GrandparentMethod() {return parent.GrandparentMethod();}

private:
    Parent parent;
};
```

Comment: Sadly, that would require to change Parent. Still a valid solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "cleaner" way.

Public inheritance expresses is-a relationship, and private does not. Once you marked that your `Child` is not `Parent`, your lost all claims to say that `Child` is a `Grandparent` - you broke transitivity chain. The only way to establish `Child` as a `Grandparent` is to **also** inherit it from `Grandparent` - but I am pretty sure you do not want to go this road.

Comment: Technically, Child is still Parent privately. This properly can be used in its private methods, for instance. The fact that it can't expose part but not all of that inheritance publicly is a pity, but I see it as a language shortcoming rather than something which is fundamentally incorrect

Answer (score 0):

There is a conceptual problem with implementing `Child` in terms of `Parent`, but only making it a `Grandparent`:

It implies that `Parent`'s contract is broken, meaning the implementation of `Child` intimately depends on the particulars of the implementation of `Parent`. We use abstraction and encapsulation isolating us from those details for a reason.

Otherwise, you could simply make `Child` a `Parent` too.

Therefore, C++ never added any syntax to allow this.

Comment: I want to expose the inherited property of being `Grandparent` in `Child`, but not the rest of the Parent's interface. It's up to `Child` to define its own interface any way it wants, and grant any sort of partial access to what it has access to by itself. The `using` directive allows doing exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Grandparent {
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Parent: public Grandparent {
public:
  virtual void foo() final { std::cout << "Dance!\n"; }
};


template<class D>
struct proxy_Grandparent:Grandparent {
  virtual void foo() final {
    return proxy().foo();
  }
private:
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const* self() const { return static_cast<D const*>(this); }
  decltype(auto) proxy() {
    return self()->get_proxy();
  }
};

class Child: Parent,
  public proxy_Grandparent<Child>
{
  friend class proxy_Grandparent<Child>;
private:
  Parent& get_proxy() { return *this; }
};
```

this has two copies of `Grandparent` in it; if `Grandparent` is an interface this isn't all that problematic.

Really, you should change `Parent` inheritance into a fully has-a:

```
class Child:
  public proxy_Grandparent<Child>
{
  friend class proxy_Grandparent<Child>;
private:
  Parent parent;
  Parent& get_proxy() { return parent; }
};
```

Comment: Late reply, I know... But if `Parent` gets a private member there's no use for the proxy any more, just inherit publicly from `Child` ;)